# Connecting to Spark SQL on EMR using JDBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, emr

I have spark running on EMR and i have been trying to connect to spark-SQL from SQLWorkbench using the JDBC hive drivers, but in vain. I have started the thrift server on the EMR and i'm able to connect to Hive on port 10000(default) from Tableau/SQL Workbench. When i try to run a query, it fires a Tez/Hive job. However, i want to run the query using Spark. Within the EMR box, I'm able to connect to SparkSQL using beeline and run a query as a spark job. Resource manager shows that the beeline query is running as a spark job, while the query running through SQLWorkbench, is running a hive/Tez job.

When i checked the logs, i found that the thrift server to connect to spark was running on port 10001(default). 
When i fire up beeline, the entries come up for connection and sql that i'm running. However, when the same connection parameters are used to connect form SQLWorkbench/Tableau, it has an exception without much details. the exception just say connection ended.

I tried running on a custom port by passing the parameters, beeline works, but not through jdbc connection.

Any help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. I was able to connect to SparkSQL from Tableau and the reason i was not able to connect was we were bringing up the thrift service as root. Not sure why it would matter, i had to change the permission on the log folder to the current user(not root) and bring up the thrift service, which enabled me to connect without any issues.